ECS Fargate: return the essential container(s) exit code
Explanation
I am currently using Fargate on Amazon ECS. In my setup, I have a task definition that includes two containers:

Python code container: Runs the main application logic.
Ephemeral service container: Supports the Python code by providing a temporary service that the Python code relies on (Selenium-hub).

Problem
I want the following behavior:

When the Python code completes its execution, it should exit cleanly.
Simultaneously, the ephemeral service container should be terminated.

However, I'm running into an issue with how ECS handles the essential property in the task definition. When I set essential to true for the Python container, ECS sends a SIGTERM signal to the ephemeral service container once the Python container finishes. This results in the ephemeral service container returning a non-zero exit code, which is not desirable.
Desired Behavior
I need ECS to logically AND the return codes of only the essential containers, meaning that the non-essential containers' exit codes should not affect the overall task status. Specifically, I want the task to only consider the exit code of the Python container, ignoring the exit code of the ephemeral service container when determining if the task succeeded or failed.
Question
Is there any way or tricky solution to overcome this issue?

As @MedAgou mentioned, there isn't a straightforward way to handle this specific scenario (i.e., managing signals or modifying the exit code in a non-essential sidecar container).
Here are two approaches to resolve this issue when using selenium-hub and Python code containers:

Creating a Custom Image: You could create a custom Docker image that combines the functionality of both containers. However, this approach increases system complexity and creates a tightly coupled codebase, which is generally not recommended.

Modifying the Entry Point of the Selenium Hub Container: A more flexible solution involves modifying the entry point of the selenium-hub container. I explored this repository and adapted the entry_point.sh script as follows:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

NODE_CONFIG_DIRECTORY=${NODE_CONFIG_DIRECTORY:-"/opt/bin"}
#==============================================
# OpenShift or non-sudo environments support
# https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/creating_images/guidelines.html#openshift-specific-guidelines
#==============================================

if ! whoami &> /dev/null; then
  if [ -w /etc/passwd ]; then
    echo "${USER_NAME:-default}:x:$(id -u):0:${USER_NAME:-default} user:${HOME}:/sbin/nologin" >> /etc/passwd
  fi
fi

/usr/bin/supervisord --configuration /etc/supervisord.conf &

SUPERVISOR_PID=$!

function shutdown {
    echo "The following line does the trick!"
    exit 0
}

trap shutdown SIGTERM SIGINT
wait ${SUPERVISOR_PID}

Dockerfile:
ARG IMAGE_TAG=4.23.1-20240820
FROM selenium/standalone-chrome:${IMAGE_TAG}

LABEL maintainer="Mostafa"

COPY modified-entry-point.sh /opt/bin/modified-entry-point.sh
RUN chmod +x /opt/bin/modified-entry-point.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/bin/modified-entry-point.sh"]



This script ensures that when the Python container exits, the selenium-hub container handles the termination gracefully without causing a non-zero exit code. This approach keeps your services loosely coupled and maintains the desired behavior in ECS.

This is the expected behavior as you marked your Python container as essential, from here :

ECS terminate the non essential tasks by sending a SIGTERM to the non essential containers, after a timeout of 30 seconds (tiemout by default) it sends a SIGKILL to force the stop of container.
So what you need is to handle the SIGTERM signal in your "non essential" containers and do whatever they need to do to clean up and exit properly, in brievety you need  something like this example with Python from here :
def shutdown_handler(signal: int, frame: FrameType) -> None:
    """Gracefully shutdown app."""
    logger.info("Signal received, safely shutting down.")
    database.shutdown()
    middleware.logging_flush()
    print("Exiting process.", flush=True)
    sys.exit(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # handles Ctrl-C locally
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, shutdown_handler)

    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=8080, debug=True)
else:
    # handles Cloud Run container termination
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, shutdown_handler)

And also instruct ECS to pass signals to process inside conatiners by enabling initProcessEnabled check the docs from here
An intersting AWS post for handling signals with ECS

Thank you for your answer. I don’t want to modify the default image of the second container. Is there any solution for this purpose?

Enable initProcessEnabled in the second container to let the process intercept the SIGTERM signal and hope your process in the container can handle this by default, otherwise I don't see any alternatives as this is how processes and signals works

Let me give it a try. The second container is Docker-Selenium.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work! :(

can you set essential to false for this container ?the Docker-Selenium one and let the value true for the python one ?

I did the same. The python code is essential and depends on the selenium one to be in a start state.
